# Modify Bean definition in library xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm forced to use some pretty old library

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>super.old.library</groupId>
   <artifactId>old</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

That library use real time bean creation to create bean of class X from file `old-config-file.xml`:

```
class OldClassFromOldLibrary {
   ...
   X getBean() {
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"old-config-file.xml"});
        return ctx.getBean("myProblematicBean", X.class);
   }
   ...
}
```

The problem is class X have some property that I need to change,
part of `old-config-file.xml` file:

```
<bean id="myProblematicBean"
    class="X">
    <property name="a" ref="aa" />
    <property name="b" ref="bb" />
</bean>
```

I want to replace property `b` with property `c` with a different ref.

I've already tried to use `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`:

```
@Bean
   public BeanFactoryPostProcessor postProcessor() {
      return configurableListableBeanFactory -> {

         BeanDefinition myProblematicBean = configurableListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition("myProblematicBean");
         MutablePropertyValues props = myProblematicBean.getPropertyValues();
         props.removePropertyValue("b");
         props.add("c", new Value());
      };
   }
```

but it's not working because the whole `old-config-file.xml` is loaded later in the runtime.

So the question is, how to replace `b` property with `c` in that case?